# Telegram Keyboard layout/commands

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I already know how to setup the custom keybord layout but so far I haven't found a way to show different "text"  on the buttons than what is send if you push it. E.g.:

```py
kb = [
    [telegram.KeyboardButton(text='/new')],
    [telegram.KeyboardButton(text='Edit')],
]
kb_markup = telegram.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(kb)`
```

It returns the text given and there doesnt seem to be an option to specify what should be returned/shown on screen upon clicking. Upon starting conversation with a bot it says "Start" but sends `/start`, is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `KeyboardButton` it is always returning the button text as messages sent from the user, if you want the data sent back to the bot not being shown/different from the button text, try using `InlineKeyboardButton`

And as for the `/start` button, it is on telegram's side, we cannot change that.